# How to find out the source branch of a merge changeset?

Tags: c#, tfs, merge, tfs-sdk, tfvc

The QueryHistory(destination) function returns a collection of changesets. Some of these changesets contain merge actions. Which function or property could identify the source branch to show where the merged code comes from?

Answer (score 3):

A `Changeset` object has a list of `Items`, each item has a property which returns the `MergeSources`. `MergeSource` has a property called `ServerItem`.

By following this lead you now have an item that is part of another branch. Use the `VersionControlServer.QueryRootBranchObjects` if you need the branchroot of that item.

Remember that one changeset can contain multiple merges across multiple branches.